# No Segue with Identifier Error in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, uiviewcontroller, segue, ibaction

I am trying to use the `performSegueWithIndentifier` function to to create a segue from one `ViewController` to the next. But, when I press the button with the `UITApGestureRecognizer` connected to it, the View shifts to the debugger panel.

Here is the error it is displaying:

```
ContaminateTargetViewController: has no segue with identifier 'showMasterChemistryViewController'
```

(I cut out the personal Info)

Here is the ViewControllers Class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ContaminateTargetViewController: UIViewController {
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showMasterChemistryViewController" {
            let chemistryMasterViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ChemistryMasterViewController
        }

    }
@IBAction func showPlaylistDetail(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showMasterChemistryViewController", sender: sender)
}
}
```

I also previously had to manual segues from the 2 buttons I have on the `ViewController` and recently deleted them to switch over to the `UITapGestureRecognizer` for the convenience. I am wondering if I have an error in my code that I do not see or if previously deleting the manual segues from the `View` is causing this error. If the problem is rooting from the previously deleted manual segues please tell me how to fix this in your error. If the problem is rooting form the code, please leave the code I should add, delete, or substitute.

Any suggestions or input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error is called when you do not have the requested segue connected to your view controller. Are you sure that you have the two view controllers connected via a segue named "showMasterChemistryViewController" on your storyboard?

Comment: How would I create that segue on the storyboard?

Comment: Control drag from either the story boards itself or your button to the other story board. Then click on this segue and name it the same as your prepareForSegue identifier